# Algorithm for grouping points on a map and cluster must have the same sum of a 3rd feature

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, data-science, geo

I'm looking for an algorithm for grouping points (43429) on a map (latitude/longitude):

```
latitude longitude expenses

603680.0 2270029.0 272.0

618559.0 2219632.0 385.0 . . .
```

However, all the clusters must have the same sum of the third feature (expenses).

The algorithm like kmeans don't make cluster with same "weight".

Do you know algorithm to do this ?
I used to use python or R

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nathan, is that an optimization problem? you want an algorithm to group by the sum of expenses but without restrictions or a gap (how different the sum of the 3rd variable you may allow) the solution is either infinite or impossible depending on data. A reproducible example may help

Comment: Hi ! I juste want k clusters and it must have approximately the same sum of expenses (The sums are in billion, a diffrence of 1 billion is acceptable)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution, just brute force.
What you're asking is not an easy computational problem (you can read about it: **multi-way partition problem**).

here is my brute force R solution assuming your data is a data frame:

```
k <- 3 # define how many clusters you want


#A really simple gleedy clustering algorithm, basically you start each list with an elemnt and add the next element to the lowest scoring list
clustering <- function(df,k){
clusters <- list()
for (r in 1:k) {
clusters[[r]] <- df[r,]
}
for (i in 4:nrow(df)){
  a = data.frame(sum(clusters[[1]]$expenses))
  for (j in 2:k) {
    a = rbind(a,sum(clusters[[j]]$expenses))
  }
  minimo = which.min(a[,1])
  clusters[[minimo]] <- rbind(clusters[[minimo]],df[i,])
}
return(clusters)
}

#calculate the difference between the lowest and highest list
distance <- function(){
  A <- clustering(df,k)
  for (k in 1:k) {
    start <- c(start,sum(A[[k]]$expenses))  
  }
  distance <- max(start) - min(start) 
  return(distance)
}


#repeat the process with a diferent starting point and save the clusters which has the lowest variance
max.distance = distance()
Clusters <- clustering(df,k)
for (i in 2:50) {
df <- slice(df, sample(1:n()))
g=distance()
if (max.distance>g) {
  max.distance <- distance()
  Clusters <- clustering(df,k)
}
}
```